# Laravel 8's session usage

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-session

Hello everyone in here.

I have chosen the laravel's database session method and want to store each registering user's Id in my sessions table precisely in the 'user_id' so that I can check if a user is connected or not.

For that I processed this way

In the controller file

```
Class RootController{

  Public function registration(Request $request) {

    $request->validate([

       'prenom' => ['required',....], 

       'nom' => ['required',....], 

       'mail' => ['required',....], 

       'password' => ['required',....]

    ]) ;

    /*now I create the user's account*/

    $user= Client::create([

       'prenom' => $request->prenom, 

       'nom' => $request->nom, 

       'mail' => $request->mail, 

       'password' => Hash::make($request->password) 

    ]);

    /*then now I insert the id of the user just registered*/ 

    session(['user_id' => $user->id]);

    });

    return Redirect::To("logged_in/". $user->id);

  }

}
```

In order to store the user's Id in sessions.user_id colomn.

Subsequently, the sessions.user_id column remains filled with Null after registration, any help please, .

Comment: the session data that you can use is stored in a single column, 'payload', in the table ... that `user_id` field on that table is set separately on write

Comment: So I can't store anything on 'user_id'?